# Suppress Plotting of heatmap

Tags: r

How can I suppress the plot from `heatmap` in the `stats` package?

```
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
hv <- heatmap(x)
hv
```

I want to get `hv` without calling a graphics device.

Comment: you don't even want to send to a null device? `png("/dev/nul"); x  <- as.matrix(mtcars); hv <- heatmap(x)`, or I guess `png('NUL')` if you're running windows

Comment: You might want to look at `heatmap.2` in the `gplots` package. Much less painful to use in general.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best idea but here's an approach:

```
x  <- as.matrix(mtcars)
hv <- heatmap(x)
hv

suppress_plot <- function(...) {
    tdir <- tempdir()
    png(file.path(tdir, "out.png"))
    out <- eval(substitute(...())[[1]])
    dev.off()
    out
}

suppress_plot(heatmap(x))
```

Comment: this still opens a device does it not

Comment: @rawr yes.  But at least it's not in the interactive session (what I meant by suppress a plot).  This is the most generalizable idea thus far.  I'm hoping for something better.